# Getting variable assignments from bbclass

Tags: python, yocto, bitbake, openembedded

I am writing a bbclass from which I would like to work with files stored in another folder of the layer.

Using `bitbake -e (recipe) | grep ^BBPATH=` get the list of PATH I would like to use to find files I need in the bbclass.

```
BBPATH="/home/<user>/.../yocto/sources/poky/meta-poky:/home/<user>/.../yocto/build:/home/<user>/.../yocto/sources/meta-test:..."
```

However, I do not get the same ouput invoking getVar(), which simply returns only the path linked to the build directory.

/ How can I dump the BBPATH variable as used by bitbake in the bbclass ?

Comment: Maybe tell us more what your bbclass should do to check if there are no other ways? It seems there is a common pattern that looks like `bb.utils.which(self.d.getVar('BBPATH'), filepath)`?

Comment: Thanks. bbclass defines tasks to sign binaries which are compiled and packaged by the recipe. Files I am trying to find and use are the generated custom keys.

Comment: Maybe you can check [uefi-sign.bbclass](http://git.yoctoproject.org/cgit/cgit.cgi/meta-intel/tree/classes/uefi-sign.bbclass) for an example on signing files?